# dyld[3745]: Library not loaded: @rpath/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages (no such file) on real device

Tags: ios, swift, linker, runtime

I know that this question has been asked and answered multiple times but still my issue persists.

I am creating a framework in XCode and I am trying to implement OneSignal for Push Notification inside the framework (It will come handy for the dev who implements the framework).

I integrated OneSignal v5.0.4 into my framework using Swift Package Manager, and wrapped the integration code of OneSignal with my framework (The developer will use my code to add OneSignal),

```swift
// code from library

import Foundation
import OneSignalFramework
import OneSignalExtension

public class RemoteNotification{
    
    public class func initialize(withLaunchOptions: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
    
       let notificationId = "NOTIFICATION_ID"
        
        OneSignal.initialize(notificationId, withLaunchOptions: withLaunchOptions)
    }
    
    public class func requestNotificationPermission() {
        OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission(nil, fallbackToSettings: true)
    }
    
    public class func didReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest( _ request: UNNotificationRequest, with replacementContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?, withContentHandler contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)!){
        OneSignal.didReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest(request, with: replacementContent, withContentHandler: contentHandler)
    }
    
    public class func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpireRequest(request: UNNotificationRequest, content: UNMutableNotificationContent?) {
        OneSignalExtension.serviceExtensionTimeWillExpireRequest(request, with: content)
    }
    
    public init(){}
}
```

And Add this code to the app according to the OneSignal [doc](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup). The code works completely fine on Simulator (iOS 17.0.1) and I am receiving the notifivations, but it crashes using a real device. I used an iPad Air 5th gen (iPadOS 17.0.3) and iPhone 14 (iOS 17.1.1) and it crashes with both devices.

I implement the code like so:

```swift
// demo app
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

// framework is imported

      RemoteNotifications.initialize(withLaunchOptions: launchOptions)
      
      RemoteNotifications.requestNotificationPermission()
    
    return true
  }
}
```

I am currently using XCode 15.0.1, I did some research and some people faced the same error after XCode 15, so I redownloaded XCode 14 and the issue persists. I also took care of the `@rpath` in `Build Settings` > `Dynamic Library Install Name Base` and it still crashes on real devices. `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` is set to `YES`. And also I made sure that OneSignal is in `General` > `Frameworks and Libraries`.
[image]

And also in `Build Phases`> `Link Binary With Libraries`
[image]

> These are added to the Framework and not the Demo App

Here is the debug console after running the project:

```
dyld[3745]: Library not loaded: @rpath/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages
  Referenced from: <4057D330-C1A6-3B2E-BE35-1460B73BB975> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F29679A9-350F-41D1-9801-F364550350B7/APPNAME.app/Frameworks/LIBRARYNAME.framework/LIBRARYNAME
  Reason: tried:
 '/PATH_TO/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-fiwhvicultvplneiexsqyutgnyfb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages' (no such file),
 '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/PATH_TO/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-fiwhvicultvplneiexsqyutgnyfb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages' (no such file),
 '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F29679A9-350F-41D1-9801-F364550350B7/APPNAME.app/Frameworks/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages' (no such file),
 '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F29679A9-350F-41D1-9801-F364550350B7/APPNAME.app/Frameworks/LIBRARYNAME.framework/Frameworks/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages' (no such file), 
'/PATH_TO/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-fiwhvicultvplneiexsqyutgnyfb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages' (no such file),
 '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/PATH_TO/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-fiwhvicultvplneiexsqyutgnyfb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages' (no such file),
 '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F29679A9-350F-41D1-9801-F364550350B7/APPNAME.app/Frameworks/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages' (no such file),
 '/PATH_TO/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-fiwhvicultvplneiexsqyutgnyfb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages' (no such file),
 '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/PATH_TO/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-fiwhvicultvplneiexsqyutgnyfb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages' (no such file),
 '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F29679A9-350F-41D1-9801-F364550350B7/APPNAME.app/Frameworks/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages' (no such file)
```

> `LIBRARYNAME` = My framework I created
>
> `APPNAME` = The demo app

when I run `otool -l <exefile>`, here is the output:

```
MyMAc@MyMAcs-MacBook-Pro LIBRARYNAME.framework % otool -l LIBRARYNAME
LIBRARYNAME:
Load command 0
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 1512
  segname __TEXT
   vmaddr 0x0000000000000000
   vmsize 0x00000000000e0000
  fileoff 0
 filesize 917504
  maxprot 0x00000005
 initprot 0x00000005
   nsects 18
    flags 0x0
Section
  sectname __text
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000000004000
      size 0x00000000000c3eb0
    offset 16384
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x80000400
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __stubs
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000c7eb0
      size 0x00000000000011d0
    offset 818864
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x80000408
 reserved1 0 (index into indirect symbol table)
 reserved2 12 (size of stubs)
Section
  sectname __objc_methlist
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000c9080
      size 0x0000000000000080
    offset 823424
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __const
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000c9100
      size 0x0000000000004ed0
    offset 823552
     align 2^4 (16)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __cstring
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000cdfd0
      size 0x000000000000281c
    offset 843728
     align 2^4 (16)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000002
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __swift5_typeref
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000d07ec
      size 0x00000000000047ae
    offset 853996
     align 2^1 (2)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __swift5_capture
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000d4f9c
      size 0x0000000000000818
    offset 872348
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __constg_swiftt
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000d57b4
      size 0x000000000000213c
    offset 874420
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __swift5_reflstr
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000d78f0
      size 0x0000000000001096
    offset 882928
     align 2^4 (16)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __swift5_fieldmd
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000d8988
      size 0x00000000000019f0
    offset 887176
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __swift5_proto
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000da378
      size 0x0000000000000434
    offset 893816
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __swift5_types
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000da7ac
      size 0x00000000000002c0
    offset 894892
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_methname
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000daa6c
      size 0x0000000000000920
    offset 895596
     align 2^0 (1)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000002
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __swift5_assocty
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000db38c
      size 0x0000000000000618
    offset 897932
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __swift5_builtin
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000db9a4
      size 0x0000000000000078
    offset 899492
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __swift5_protos
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000dba1c
      size 0x0000000000000040
    offset 899612
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __unwind_info
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000dba5c
      size 0x0000000000001910
    offset 899676
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __eh_frame
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x00000000000dd370
      size 0x0000000000000d24
    offset 906096
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x6800000b
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Load command 1
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 392
  segname __DATA_CONST
   vmaddr 0x00000000000e0000
   vmsize 0x0000000000008000
  fileoff 917504
 filesize 32768
  maxprot 0x00000003
 initprot 0x00000003
   nsects 4
    flags 0x10
Section
  sectname __got
   segname __DATA_CONST
      addr 0x00000000000e0000
      size 0x0000000000001370
    offset 917504
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000006
 reserved1 380 (index into indirect symbol table)
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __const
   segname __DATA_CONST
      addr 0x00000000000e1370
      size 0x00000000000058c8
    offset 922480
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_classlist
   segname __DATA_CONST
      addr 0x00000000000e6c38
      size 0x00000000000000d8
    offset 945208
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x10000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_imageinfo
   segname __DATA_CONST
      addr 0x00000000000e6d10
      size 0x0000000000000008
    offset 945424
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Load command 2
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 792
  segname __DATA
   vmaddr 0x00000000000e8000
   vmsize 0x0000000000010000
  fileoff 950272
 filesize 32768
  maxprot 0x00000003
 initprot 0x00000003
   nsects 9
    flags 0x0
Section
  sectname __objc_const
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000000000e8000
      size 0x0000000000001560
    offset 950272
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_selrefs
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000000000e9560
      size 0x0000000000000360
    offset 955744
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x10000005
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_classrefs
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000000000e98c0
      size 0x0000000000000108
    offset 956608
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x10000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __objc_data
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000000000e99c8
      size 0x00000000000001b0
    offset 956872
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __data
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000000000e9b78
      size 0x0000000000002d51
    offset 957304
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __s_async_hook
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000000000ec8d0
      size 0x0000000000000190
    offset 968912
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __swift56_hooks
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000000000eca60
      size 0x00000000000000b0
    offset 969312
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __bss
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000000000ecb10
      size 0x0000000000007720
    offset 0
     align 2^4 (16)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000001
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __common
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x00000000000f4230
      size 0x0000000000000390
    offset 0
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000001
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Load command 3
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __LINKEDIT
   vmaddr 0x00000000000f8000
   vmsize 0x0000000000120000
  fileoff 983040
 filesize 1165168
  maxprot 0x00000001
 initprot 0x00000001
   nsects 0
    flags 0x0
Load command 4
          cmd LC_ID_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name @rpath/LIBRARYNAME.framework/LIBRARYNAME (offset 24)
   time stamp 1 Thu Jan  1 02:00:01 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 5
      cmd LC_DYLD_CHAINED_FIXUPS
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 983040
 datasize 31648
Load command 6
      cmd LC_DYLD_EXPORTS_TRIE
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 1014688
 datasize 59448
Load command 7
     cmd LC_SYMTAB
 cmdsize 24
  symoff 1079304
   nsyms 26803
  stroff 1512160
 strsize 636048
Load command 8
            cmd LC_DYSYMTAB
        cmdsize 80
      ilocalsym 0
      nlocalsym 23895
     iextdefsym 23895
     nextdefsym 2168
      iundefsym 26063
      nundefsym 740
         tocoff 0
           ntoc 0
      modtaboff 0
        nmodtab 0
   extrefsymoff 0
    nextrefsyms 0
 indirectsymoff 1508152
  nindirectsyms 1002
      extreloff 0
        nextrel 0
      locreloff 0
        nlocrel 0
Load command 9
     cmd LC_UUID
 cmdsize 24
    uuid 98F83197-62C6-3B3C-9244-614AA2D0799C
Load command 10
      cmd LC_BUILD_VERSION
  cmdsize 32
 platform 2
    minos 15.0
      sdk 17.0
   ntools 1
     tool 3
  version 1015.7
Load command 11
      cmd LC_SOURCE_VERSION
  cmdsize 16
  version 0.0
Load command 12
          cmd LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO_64
      cmdsize 24
     cryptoff 16384
    cryptsize 901120
      cryptid 0
          pad 0
Load command 13
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name @rpath/OneSignalInAppMessages.framework/OneSignalInAppMessages (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 14
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 72
         name @rpath/OneSignalUser.framework/OneSignalUser (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 15
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name @rpath/OneSignalNotifications.framework/OneSignalNotifications (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 16
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 80
         name @rpath/OneSignalOutcomes.framework/OneSignalOutcomes (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 17
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 80
         name @rpath/OneSignalOSCore.framework/OneSignalOSCore (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 18
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 72
         name @rpath/OneSignalCore.framework/OneSignalCore (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 19
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 80
         name @rpath/OneSignalFramework.framework/OneSignalFramework (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 20
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 80
         name @rpath/OneSignalExtension.framework/OneSignalExtension (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 21
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 80
         name @rpath/OneSignalLocation.framework/OneSignalLocation (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 22
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 2048.1.101
compatibility version 300.0.0
Load command 23
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 228.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 24
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1336.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 25
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 2.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 26
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 27
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 112
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/AppTrackingTransparency.framework/AppTrackingTransparency (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 28
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 96
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 2048.1.101
compatibility version 150.0.0
Load command 29
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 30
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 80
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 61040.2.2
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 31
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 80
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 5.0.83
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 32
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 80
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 7082.1.111
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 33
cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 104
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/UserNotifications (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 34
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 96
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/_AVKit_SwiftUI.framework/_AVKit_SwiftUI (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 35
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1600.151.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 36
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 72
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 2180.79.1
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 37
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 5.9.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 38
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 5.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 39
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 72
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 120.100.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 40
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreImage.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 2.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 41
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreMIDI.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 6.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 42
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 3045.79.1
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 43
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftDarwin.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 0.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 44
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 72
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftDataDetection.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 755.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 45
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftDispatch.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 34.0.2
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 46
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 72
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftFileProvider.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1681.0.14
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 47
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftMetal.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 341.16.2
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 48
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftOSLog.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 4.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 49
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 8.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 50
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 3.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 51
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 80
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftUniformTypeIdentifiers.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 793.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 52
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftos.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1040.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 53
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftsimd.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 18.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 54
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftFoundation.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 55
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftUIKit.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 56
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 72
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 120.100.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 57
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 160
         PATH_TO/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-fiwhvicultvplneiexsqyutgnyfb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks (offset 12)
Load command 58
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 40
         path @executable_path/Frameworks (offset 12)
Load command 59
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 40
         path @loader_path/Frameworks (offset 12)
Load command 60
      cmd LC_FUNCTION_STARTS
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 1074136
 datasize 5168
Load command 61
      cmd LC_DATA_IN_CODE
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 1079304
 datasize 0
MyMAc@MyMAcs-MacBook-Pro LIBRARYNAME.framework %
```

Comment: So is the `.framework` being written to your app bundle?

Comment: @trojanfoe if you are talking about the necessary steps to implement my framework to the app yes. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, I meant that you need to look at the built app bundle in `DerivedData` to verify the `.framework` is there.  Once you have verified that we can go through how to verify that `rpath` is set correctly in the main executable.

Comment: Yes I went through the `DerivedData` and all the necessary frameworks and files are there in the `debug-iphoneos` path.

Comment: OK, next you need to verify the `rpath` in the executable itself.  Please update your question with the output of `otool -L <exefile>` and then `otool -l <exefile>` (lowercase `L`) looking for all `LC_RPATH` sections (there is probably only one: `@executable_path/Frameworks`).

Comment: I can see from what you've posted the runtime linker is attempting to look in `@executable_path/PackageFrameworks` for some reason...

Comment: I couldn't post the `otool -L` command because it is too long, but the lower cased one shows the `rpath`

Comment: Runpath Search path: `$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks`

Dynamic Library Install Name : `$(DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE:standardizepath)/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)`

this is what I did in the build settings of my framework. IDK why it is saying `PackageFrameworks`